# jquery each css array

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have made an each statement which iterates through each class item found. At the same time there is another item with a different class but has the same key. I am needing to get the key from the first each and put it into the 2nd item without having to loop a second time.

```
$('.searchby').each(function(k,v){ // looping through .searchby
    $(v).live('change',function(){ // when .searchby drop down changed do this
        selv = $(this).val(); // get value of drop down
        $.post('file.php',{ 'val' : selv },function(data){

            // Below is where I need what I need to happen.
            // Previously I had .searchby as id but need multiple.
            // So, what I need it to do is like php.
            // $('.searchfield[k]).html(data); // <-- like this

            $('#searchfield').html(data);


        },'html'); // html, xml, script, json
    });
});
```

--EDIT--

First, the v in $(v).live should be $(this).live
2nd, I am wanting to convert the single/id pull script to a multi pull script. So, I wrote this which works.

```
$('.searchby').each(function(k,v){
    $(this).change(function(){
        selv = $(this).val();
        $.post('file.php',{
            'val' : selv
        },function(data){
            $('.searchfield').each(function(kk,vv){
                if(k == kk) $(vv).html(data);
            });
            //$('#searchfield').html(data);
        },'html'); // html, xml, script, json
    });
});
```

But I would like to be able to take the inner .each out and replace it with:

```
$('.searchfield:eq('+k+')') <-- something like this if I can get it to work
```

So the solution is this:

```
$('.searchby').each(function(k,v){
    $(this).change(function(){
        selv = $(this).val();
        $.post('file.php',{
            'val' : selv
        },function(data){
            $('.searchfield:eq('+k+')').html(data);
        },'html'); // html, xml, script, json
    });
});
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Just looking ... I would think that or adding a local (e.g. `var tempk = k;`) to the function it is passed into then just referencing it in the second nested function should work with JavaScript's scoping rules.

Comment: That being said (sorry for the double post, forgot to complete the thought), you will still need to 'generate' the identifier:
`$('#searchfield['+k+']').html(data);`
or similar.

Comment: `k` is already a local, because it's a function parameter.

Comment: Isn't "live" intended more for CSS strings rather than jQuery selection sets? Otherwise what's the point? Nothing new will ever show up in $(v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your `$(v)`above is incorrect, because `$(...).each()` provides its callback with a single documented argument (the index).

To achieve the equivalent of `$('.searchfield[k]')`, there's an actually quite close syntax available:

```
$('.searchfield:eq('+k+')')
```

Comment: I put this code into my code and gave the final version in the top post.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. You talk of classes, but then your code uses `$('#searchfield')`, which is used to select elements with the given ID.

Assuming you really want to select elements with a given class (which is more correct, as there should not be elements with duplicated ID), and if there are exactly one element with class `searchfield` for each elements selected by `$.each()`, then you can use `$($('.searchfield')[k]).html(data)`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `$(...)[k]` returns the DOM element, not a jQuery object, so you would have to write `$($(...)[k]).html()` instead.